# How to show that $\{1, e^{ix}, e^{-ix}\}$ is a linearly independent set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the vector space of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. If $W$ is a subspace spanned by $\beta$ = $\{1, e^{ix}, e^{-ix}\}$, show that $\beta$ is a basis for $W$.

I think I am very confused - I know I just have to show that $\beta$ is linearly independent, which means I need to show that

$a+be^{ix}+ce^{-ix} = 0 \Rightarrow a = b = c = 0$. But if I have $x=0, a=3, b=-2, c=-1$, then the left side still equals $0$ but $a, b, c \neq 0$.

I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. Please advise :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to show that 
$$ a + be^{ix} + ce^{-ix} = 0 \Rightarrow a, b, c = 0 $$
*for all $x$*.

The vector space you're considering is linear combinations of *functions*, so the zero on the right of the equation is the zero function, not the number zero.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I wasn't sure if it was the correct way to think about it. Then I have the left side equals the zero polynomial. Does this mean I can say that the left side equals the zero polynomial only if they have the same coefficients, which means a = b = c = 0? Is this enough?

Comment: The "for all $x$" quantifier should only be for the equation on the LHS of $\Rightarrow$!

Comment: @Jared Equating coefficients like with polynomials is actually using (and assuming) the fact that the powers of $x$ are linearly independent functions. This is a fact that should be proven at some point in your studies. Here, you are expected to prove these functions are linearly independent. I suggest picking three values of $x$ to form three linear equations of $a, b, c$. Unless you get very unlucky, you should find that there is only the trivial solution.

Comment: @TheoBendit ah okay, but what do we do about the unlucky cases?

Comment: @Jared Pick again! If it fails a second time, I'd start wondering if they're linearly dependent. Try to avoid, say, common roots of the functions, but mostly, you can't really go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the vectors are linearly dependent, the equality

$$a+be^{ix}+ce^{-ix} = 0$$

should hold for some $a,b,c$ for any $x$ but you have considered a particular case with $x=0$.

Indeed we have that

$$a+be^{ix}+ce^{-ix} = 0 \quad \forall x \iff a = b = c = 0$$

and the vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there are $_1,z_2,z_3\in\mathbb C$ such that $z_1+z_2e^{ix}+z_3e^{-ix}=0$. Then:

- if $x=0$, we have $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$;
- if $x=\pi$, we have $z_1-z_2-z_3=0$;
- if $x=\frac\pi2$, we have $z_1+iz_2-iz_3=0$.

What does this tell you about $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$?

Comment: I see now that this says that z_1 = z_2 = z_3 = 0. My question now is, why does it suffice to show this for only 3 different values of x? Aren't there choices of x such that z_1 or z_2 or z_3 is nonzero?

Comment: It's more than just $z_1=z_2=z_3$! Solve the system and you will get that $z_1=z_2=z_3=0$. Or can can just compute the matrix of the coefficients of the system and see that its determinant is not $0$ (it is equal to $4i$).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I edited it -- I did see that each variable is 0. I just am confused about how I should think about the choices of x that don't give me 0, 0, 0. Why do these not matter?

Comment: Because from those choices you reach no conclusion. Suppose someone asks you whether the product of any two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ is always greater than their sum. If you take $m=3$ and $n=4$, then $m\times n>m+n$, but that isn't enough to provide an answer. On the other hand, if $m=n=2$, then $m\times n=m+n$ and then you know that the answer is negative.

Answer (score 1):

The Wronskian of $\{1, e^{ix}, e^{-ix}\}$ is

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & e^{ix} & e^{-ix} \\ 0 & ie^{ix} & -ie^{-ix} \\ 0 & -e^{ix} & -e^{-ix}\end{vmatrix} = -2i \ne 0$$

so $\{1, e^{ix}, e^{-ix}\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question above, since he obviously didn't understand what it meant for functions to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

While most of the answers given here are true, they don't really go into enough detail on what you understood wrong. When talking about the vectorspace of all functions, we need to consider any function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ to be a vector, i.e. the given $\beta$ would be denoted much more appropriately as
$$
f_1\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C},\,x\mapsto 1\\
f_2\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}, \,x\mapsto e^{ix}\\
f_3\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}, \,x\mapsto e^{-ix}\\
\beta=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$$
Now, for $f_1,f_2,f_3$ to be linearly independent, you need to show that there is no combination of $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ for which the linear combination $af_1+bf_2+cf_3$ equals the $0$ **in your vectorspace**. Here you need to make sure though that you understand what the $0$ in your vectorspace actually is: You are looking at a vectorspace which consists of functions, i.e. your $0$ is also a function, in this case the function $n\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C},\,x\mapsto 0$, the constant $0$-function. Now, when are 2 functions equal? When they attain the same value for every input. That's the reason you need to check for *every* $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The equation $af_1+bf_2+cf_3=0(=n)$ means that for every input value $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the functionvalue $af_1(x)+bf_2(x)+cf_3(x)=n(x)=0$, where $a,b$ and $c$ do **not** depend on $x$.

Comment: So, I can say that the only case where every x is sent to zero is when a, b, c are all zero, correct? I see now that I was only considering one particular case, when x = 0, but my values of a, b, c in the original post wouldn't give me an output of zero for every input.

Comment: That is correct, even though it doesn't suffice to check your particular example, you'd much rather assume it to be true for some $a,b,c$ and then prove, that $a,b,$ and $c$ must all be $0$.